# export dist-upgrade packages to file

Tags: upgrade, bash

in dist-upgrade i want to use it in init3 and i dont have X and my internet speed is low.
how to export dist-upgrade download packages to file to get another pc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command below:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y --print-uris --install-suggests | grep -o '\'http:.*\' | tr "\'" " " > /to/destination/file
```

replace `/to/destination/file` with the absolute path of the file where you want to dump the packages' uris.